# Options for card layout on website

Tags: website-design, layout, page-layout

[image]I am creating a screen which displays courses. Currently, I am using card layout. Here each card displays a course name, and a button .on click of that button, a form will open in a modal window where the user will put his details and submit it.

Is there an option to display course list apart from cards.Please consider following information.

- There are only 6 courses available.
- Only name of course and a description of not more than 5 words is to be shown for each course
- This page should only displays course list.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of your current layout? 
Will more courses be added in the future? 
I assume you are using an image with the title and the description and button?

Comment: Hi @PectoralisMajor
I have added image to the question, please refer to it
No more courses would be added to it

Comment: I apologize, but the question seems kind of vague.  There are many other options that could possibly work.  Perhaps you could explain a bit more about the issues your current layout is generating?

Comment: Oooh look a course question!

Answer (score 1):

As a page that has 2 main functions: 
1. Display all options
2. Drive traffic to the form

There is not much you can do with the layout. The user understands what each course is and will click to inquire.

However, since we are talking about courses, you might want to surface more relevant information for the user to answer all the basic questions they will have, such as Price, Time, Location, Frequency, Professor, Length, etc... this depends on your service entirely (I do not know how the business works).

With more information to show, you might want to more to a more effective layout, such as a list, rather than cards.

I also noticed for each course you separate them between basic, advanced, etc. What is the difference between these? Do you need to display more information on each? How does the business know which level the user is inquiring about? Maybe you should separate them further, 2 entries for each course type. Again, this points to a list approach.

There is a lot of missing user and business information which can help you determine the right layout. UX is never about layout or interface alone.

Answer (score 0):

If you have only this much data of a course to show on a card then you can shift your view to grid list.

Comment: Welcome to UXstackexchange! Thanks for your contribution. Could you develop your idea further? How a grid list would improve the user experience compared to cards? Maybe provide an example or wireframe.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the present layout, you got 5 cards which looks a little inconsistent. To account for future course that will be added it will be great to go with a list view( left), which once hovered over shows the exapanded view or as a card to the right.

This will reduce the clutter and fit in more information and could even have a illustration.